# incrementing sub-document key using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would really appreciate some help regarding the below noted. The problem is I want to increment the `keys` such as 'eagle', 'bear', etc by one.  My data model looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57e134097a578b11eruogf0a2cb"),
"email" : "test3@example.com",
"password" : "$2a$10$KU8vmE./gewfuh3445ryh7hDC426k0Ttd2",
"userName" : "person",
"votedFor" : [],
"polls" : [ 
    {
        "items" : {
            "eagle" : 3,
            "bear" : 5,
            "lion" : 3,
            "giraffe" : 0,
            "elephant" : 0,
            "monkey" : 0,
            "gorilla" : 0,
            "dog" : 0,
            "cat" : 0
        },
        "_id" : ObjectId("57e39435erthytvf4c16149b3fcd"),
        "pollTitle" : "if you could be any animal, which one would you be?"
    }
]
}
```

Here are the attempts I've made without success:

```
User.update({"polls._id":ObjectId("57e39435erthytvf4c16149b3fcd"),
"polls.items.bear":{$exists:true}}, {$inc:{"polls.$.items.bear":1}})
```

The above actually works with robomongo but curiously doesn't within  my app. It actually creates a new key: `"__v" :`.

The latest attempt looks something like this which is more of a desperate attempt at grabbing the whole document and manipulating it in a cumbersome way:

```
var pollItem = "bear", mongoose = require('mongoose'), 
pollID = "57e39435erthytvf4c16149b3fcd", 
id =   mongoose.Types.ObjectId(pollID);

User.findOne({"polls._id" :id},function(err,user){
             if(err){
              return err;
             }


             user.polls.forEach(function(poll){


               if(poll._id.valueOf() == pollID){

                var value = poll.items[pollItem];
                  poll.items[pollItem] = value + 1;
                  return poll;
               }
               return poll;
             })

            user.save(function(err){
              if(err){

                return (err);
              }
              console.log('successfully saved');
            })

           });
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to save the changes to the document.If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: In Mongoose, there's certainly no need to convert the string to an ObjectId type for use in queries since this is done under the hood for you and as long as it's a valid hex string.

Comment: ah, ok. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it seems you need to reference every level of the `document` in the `query` object in order to update the correct field in the `update` object. I've tried to find the documentation for this but I can't, so it's a bit of an assumption, unless some sagacious SO user could confirm this as the reason. Here's what I did:

```
User.update({"_id":ObjectId("57e134097a578b11f060a2cb"),
"polls._id":ObjectId("57e39435c4af4c16149b3fcd"),
"polls.items.dog":{$exists:true}},
{$inc:{"polls.$.items.dog":1}})
```

Hope this helps someone.